# Piano falling items animations swift/iOS

Tags: ios, game, swift

I need help / advice!
How to make such falling elements?
Is this done through a sprite or just a view, or the draw method?
I can not imagine how to do it at all
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You asked about Swift / iOS and Sprite Animation vs. view vs. draw method, so I assume, you want to implement this in an iOS App?**

If I am right, my answer would be:

Welcome to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within the [scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you think you can edit it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Please try [stackoverflow](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) to get answers for topics that are relatic to software development.

**If you really look for a software to animate this, my answer would be different:**

These kind of animations are probably not animated by hand, but by a software. Still, you *can* do this by hand of course.

I would recommend a classic 2D animation software to do this, like [Animate CC](https://www.adobe.com/de/products/animate.html), [After Effects](https://www.adobe.com/de/products/aftereffects.html) or [ToonBoom Harmony](https://www.toonboom.com/products/harmony).

If you are looking for Open Source, try [Natron](https://natrongithub.github.io/) or [Blender](https://www.blender.org/).